# How can I deprecate whole message in Protocol Buffers?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, deprecated, grpc, deprecation-warning

According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto):

**deprecated** (field option): If set to true, indicates that the field is deprecated and should not be used by new code.

Example of use:

```
message Foo {
 string old_field = 1 [deprecated=true];
}
```

- How we can deprecate the whole message?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can set [deprecated](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d428610254f0c434a8ea0ce4d75e65cdc47fe8cb/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#L580) as a top level option on the message:

```
message Foo {
   option deprecated = true;
   string old_field = 1;
}
```