# Move message to another proto file and import it

Tags: protocol-buffers

I currently have two proto files. `foo.proto` and `bar.proto`, `foo.proto` is already importing types from `bar.proto` However, I now need to make a change where `bar.proto` needs to use a message defined in `foo.proto`.

I moved the message definition from `foo` to `bar` but now I need to figure out the best way of deprecating the message from `foo` since it was removed it need to be reserver/deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a (proto3) specific way to annotate messages as deprecated and the principle is different to a deprecated field in a message.

**NOTE:** Even with fields `deprecated` is more documentary, only treated as guidance and not necessarily enforced.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787662/609290) is for proto2 but I've not used it and can't vouch for it.

I assume (!) that you need to retain the message in `foo` for existing code. If there are no dependencies, simply exclude (comment out) the message from `foo` and explain why.

As there appears no formal mechanism, I think you're going to have to rely on comments and hope that other developers respect the request.

**NOTE**: I'm unsure of the consequences of recursive dependencies (`foo` depending on `bar` and vice versa) but this is likely something you should try to avoid.